# How to use "suggest" in elasticsearch pyes?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

How to use the "suggest" feature in pyes? Cannot seem to figure it out due to poor documentation. Could someone provide a working example? None of what I tried appears to work. In the docs its listed under query, but using:

```
query = Suggest(fields="fieldname")
connectionobject.search(query=query)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, there are open issues [here](https://github.com/aparo/pyes/issues/334) and [here](https://github.com/aparo/pyes/issues/387) for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my code which runs perfectly.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

text = 'ra'
suggDoc = {
           "entity-suggest" : {
                'text' : text,
                "completion" : {
                    "field" : "suggest"
                }
            }
        }

res = es.suggest(body=suggDoc, index="auto_sugg", params=None)
print(res)
```

I used the same client mentioned on the elasticsearch site [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/index.html)
I indexed the data in the elasticsearch index by using `completion suggester` from [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html)

Comment: Since version 5, ``suggest`` API endpoint has been deprecated in favour of ``_search`` endpoint (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-suggesters.html)

Answer (score 7):

Since version 5:

> _suggest endpoint has been deprecated in favour of using suggest via _search endpoint. In 5.0, the _search endpoint has been optimized for suggest only search requests.

(from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-suggesters.html)

Better way to do this is using search api with `suggest` option

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

text = 'ra'
suggest_dictionary = {"my-entity-suggest" : {
                      'text' : text,
                      "completion" : {
                          "field" : "suggest"
                      }
                    }
                  }

query_dictionary = {'suggest' : suggest_dictionary}

res = es.search(
    index='auto_sugg',
    doc_type='entity',
    body=query_dictionary)
print(res)
```

Make sure you have indexed each document with `suggest` field

```
sample_entity= {
            'id' : 'test123',
            'name': 'Ramtin Seraj',
            'title' : 'XYZ',    
            "suggest" : {
                "input": [ 'Ramtin', 'Seraj', 'XYZ'],
                "output": "Ramtin Seraj",
                "weight" : 34   # a prior weight 
            }
          }
```

Comment: Much better since suggest endpoint is deprecated from version 5.